# Samsung Fascinate - Custom recovery without USB

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-fascinate

I have a Samsung Fascinate that has a faulty USB connection. No computer / cable connection will recognize that there is a USB connection, including Windows, Mac, Linux, and using ADB and "lsusb".

But the phone is rooted. Plain and simple, is there ANY way to flash a custom recovery without USB?

I get this when I try to flash Clockworkmod through the app or apply update.zip:

```
--Install from package...
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Verifying update package...
E: failed to verify whole-file signature
E: signature verification failed
Installation aborted
```

Comment: The only way I could think of is flashing a Recovery SD card, hopefully that can get you started.

Comment: @John thanks for the reply. I googled "flash recovery sd card android" but didn't really find anything specific -- can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

**Recovery SD**

So I found a pretty good tutorial that shows you how to make a bootable CWM recovery. It was written for the Nook Color, but I'll help you through it.

Source: http://androidforums.com/nookcolor-all-things-root/327798-guide-how-make-bootable-cwm-clockworkmod-twrp-bootable-sd-card-06-04-2013-a.html

1. You need an SD card obviously, the guide says 1 GB is good enough. To be honest I'm not even sure if you can buy a 1 GB SD card at a store anymore (you can most defiantly get them online but don't waste your money). Just go to the store and pick out the cheapest 4 or 8 GB SD card, they are pretty cheap these days. You can get them online if you want to save a couple bucks but I don't think it's worth the wait.
2. Download a bootable image file. This is what your Android device is actually going to boot up onto. Make sure you find one that matches your device.
3. You need software to burn an image to an SD card. If you have Mac OSX or Ubuntu you are in luck because those systems come with software to write images. If you are a Windows user, you can just download some software. If you don't know how to do this, just check the tutorial, their instructions are pretty good.

If you did all of the steps correctly, you should be able to plug the SD card into the device and it should boot from SD automatically.

**adb over wifi**

I'm not sure if this will help you, but maybe it will if you couldn't get the Recovery SD card working. You can use adb over wifi to talk to your Android device.

Here is a guide to get you connected to adb over wifi:

- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1685736

from there you can push a custom ROM to install over your current one (which could restore your USB connectivity).